# Updating height of a tree while inserting values through recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, height, binary-search-tree

i have written a code which inserts new values in a binary search tree through recursion. The insertion works fine. But i want to add one more thing, every time i insert an item , the height of every node will be updated at the same time. How can i do it?
The code i wrote is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
class node{
public:
    int data;
    node(int n){
        data=n;
    }
};
int i;
class avlTree{
    public:
    node* root;
    int height;
    avlTree *left;
    avlTree *right;
    avlTree(){
        root=NULL;
        height=0;
        left=NULL;
        right=NULL;
    }

    void insert(avlTree* t,int n){
        avlTree* temp=t;
        if(temp->root==NULL){
            temp->root=new node(n);
            temp->left=new avlTree();
            temp->right=new avlTree();
        }
        else{
            if(n<(temp->root->data)){
                insert(temp->left,n);
                i++;
                temp->height=i;
             }
             else{
                insert(temp->right,n);
                i++;
                temp->height=i;
             }
        }
    }
    void inorder(avlTree *v){
            if(v->root!=NULL){
                inorder(v->left);
                cout<<v->root->data<<height<<endl;
                inorder(v->right);
                //fflush(stdin);
            }
        }
};
int main()
{
    avlTree t;
    t.insert(&t,4);
    t.insert(&t,5);
    t.insert(&t,3);
    t.insert(&t,7);
    t.inorder(&t);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to do that as you add the items? If so you could use a static variable but why not make a function to get the depth separately?

Comment: i want to implement it as an avl tree, that's why i need to keep track of the height while insertion

Comment: You could make a height member variable on the node class and also a private member function in the tree class that updates the node parent's height. You would recursively update the heights using the function. I don't really know much about avl trees though so I may be talking nonsense.

Comment: But what is your question? Did you write the code only, or have you also compiled and run it? What are the results? Does it calculate the tree height wrong?...